# Two tables in one dropdown list asp.net mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 different tables and I want to make them in one drop down list, Is this possible?

this for my dropdownlist Controller.
I added some items because that items are not in table.

```
var engineer = 
(from x in up5.V_Pekerja.Where(x => x.KodeBagian == "E15320" && 
          x.NamaJabatan.ToLower().Contains("section head") == false && 
          x.NamaJabatan.ToLower().Contains("lead of") == false)
  select new 
   SelectListItem { Text = x.Nopek + " - " + x.Nama, Value = x.Nopek }).ToList();

  engineer.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "663693 - Nana Sukarna", Value = "663693" });
  engineer.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "653479 - Tri Bambang H", Value = "653479" });
  engineer.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "747522 - Apri Marlinaldi Majid", Value = "747522" });
  ViewBag.Engineer = engineer;
```

can someone please help me if this possible.. sorry for my bad english

Comment: Where is the second table used?Provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: which part is not working ??? you need to explain more

Comment: Use Dapper like ORM Framework, simply make join in SQL query or procedure and simply use that object and display the list in LINQ. Entity Framework always causes complexity in code.

Comment: So did any of the answers below help you?  If so, please make sure you mark is as the answer so that this shows as being answered.

Answer (score 0):

No idea on the 2nd table u have mention , but you can try to added to SelectListItem by :

`List<SelectListItem> table2 = new List<SelectListItem>(); //define your table2
 engineer.AddRange(table2);`

Answer (score 0):

I found the following article that looks like it has the information you need.  The loading of the dropdown is similar to how I was going to approach it.  The article below takes it a step further and show how to load the data for the selected record and display it. Depending on what you are doing that additional information may or may not be beneficial.

[C# Corner: Binding To Table To DropDown](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/bind-two-tables-in-dropdownlist-and-when-selected-show-its-related-records1)

Hope the information helps you answer your question.